# How do I display css code through php variables?

Tags: php, html, css

I have decided to utilize php with my css for better management. I have it set up so that I can incorporate variables within my "style.php" file and use them for my css code. With that said, I would also like the ability to display these variables through an echo statement. So in my main index, I want to pretty much be able to do "echo $body;" so that I can actually display the css. It will not allow me to do so.

this is my "style.php" file located in the styling folder

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");

$body = '
background-color:red;<br>
margin:0 auto;<br>
';

?>

body{
    <?php echo $body; ?>
}
```

this is my "index.php" file

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/style.php" media="screen">
<?php
include 'globals/vars.php';
?>
<title><?php echo $title; ?> - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What in your opinion are pros of that solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are including HTML tags in the CSS. The PHP all works fine, but you don't need a `<br>` at the end of every line of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can either include the CSS php script as inline CSS through an `include` or you can put the variables in a separate file, include them in your CSS page as well as your main page.

The reason you can't access `$body` in index.php, is because `$body` is declared in your CSS file which is never included in your index.php file. Instead, you are referencing the CSS file using HTML which will include only the *output* of that php script.

Alternatively, you can look into SASS or another CSS pre-processor which supports variables and other features for "easy management".

EDIT: Regarding what Chris just mentioned, if it's new lines in your CSS file that you're after, just use "\r\n" instead of `<br>`.

Comment: `$body` is both declared and used in his `style.php` file. He should have no problem accessing it.

Comment: @Chris he said "So in my main index, I want to pretty much be able to do 'echo $body;'". He can echo $body in style.php but not index.

Comment: I don't think he means that. His example code shows him accessing it in the same file and should work perfectly when he's cleaned up the CSS.

Comment: It is not accessible through the index.php, only in the style.php file. I want it to be.

Comment: @AdamDePolo Just to clarify, did removing the `<br>` tags solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `<br/>`in your code, you should use newline `\n` instead

Answer (score 0):

Style.php:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/css");
  include 'globals/vars.php';
?>

body{
  <?php echo $body; ?>
}
```

Index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/style.php" media="screen">
  <?php
    include 'globals/vars.php';
  ?>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?> - Home</title>
</head>
   <body>
     <?php echo $body; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

globals/vars.php:

```
$body = '
background-color:red;
margin:0 auto;
';
```

This should work, as you're now declaring the variable `$body` in the same scope that you are using it.